# I installed phpfreechat 1.3 on my webpage but I got this errors but I dont know what to do

Tags: php, copy, chat, chmod

```
Warning: copy(/home/beradioc/public_html/phpfreechat-1.3/src/../data/public/themes/default/sound.swf) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/beradioc/public_html/phpfreechat-1.3/src/pfctools.php on line 179

Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Operation not permitted in /home/beradioc/public_html/phpfreechat-1.3/src/pfctools.php on line 180

Warning: copy(/home/beradioc/public_html/phpfreechat-1.3/src/../data/public/themes/default/smileys/emoticon_surprised.png) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/beradioc/public_html/phpfreechat-1.3/src/pfctools.php on line 179

Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Operation not permitted in /home/beradioc/public_html/phpfreechat-1.3/src/pfctools.php on line 180

Warning: copy(/home/beradioc/public_html/phpfreechat-1.3/src/../data/public/themes/default/smileys/emoticon_waii.png) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/beradioc/public_html/phpfreechat-1.3/src/pfctools.php on line 179

Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Operation not permitted in /home/beradioc/public_html/phpfreechat-1.3/src/pfctools.php on line 180

Warning: copy(/home/beradioc/public_html/phpfreechat-1.3/src/../data/public/themes/default/smileys/weather_sun.png) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/beradioc/public_html/phpfreechat-1.3/src/pfctools.php on line 179

Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Operation not permitted in /home/beradioc/public_html/phpfreechat-1.3/src/pfctools.php on line 180

Warning: copy(/home/beradioc/public_html/phpfreechat-1.3/src/../data/public/themes/default/smileys/weather_cloudy.png) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/beradioc/public_html/phpfreechat-1.3/src/pfctools.php on line 179

Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Operation not permitted in /home/beradioc/public_html/phpfreechat-1.3/src/pfctools.php on line 180
```

Comment: Try the first listing at: goo.gl/Nk4Cg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script does not have permissions.

If you are running on your own server, use [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod). If you're running on shared hosting, try chaning permissions anyway, but it's not granted you'll be successful.

Answer (score 0):

chmod is a command for changing permissions on  files and/or directories it would appear that your script does not have sufficient permissions to do so, or to copy files around. I would seriously recommend that you study up on file permission, maybe read the READMe for phpfreechat which will probably tell you what those permissions are and go from there. If you do not have ssh access or direct access to your web server, you will probably need some help from your hosting company after you find out what files ad directories need what permissions.

a quick look at phpfreechat's page states:

Give the web server's write permissions to “phpfreechat-x.x/data/public” and “phpfreechat-x.x/data/private” directories.
If you are using FTP:

```
 CHMOD 777 phpfreechat-x.x/data/private
 CHMOD 777 phpfreechat-x.x/data/public



 If you are using SSH:

chmod 777 phpfreechat-x.x/data/*
```